# How to deploy hybris with storefront addon

Tags: deployment, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using the *b2bacceleratoraddon* and *commerceorgaddon* addons in our hybris 6.5.0.1.

For the local development it is enough to run the **ant addoninstall** command.
But what is the official way to integrate these addons in a deployment process? We tried to check-in the generated sources in the repository but that does not seem to work.

We don't want to manually install the plugin after every deployment.

Also, as we are doing our deployments with [ydeploy](https://github.com/avatria/ydeploy), is there a way to integrate this in the [ydeploy](https://github.com/avatria/ydeploy) process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ant addoninstall task is meant to be executed only once. It manipulates some files die the addon to work correctly. These files are:

- myaddon/project.properties
- mystorefront/extensioninfo.xml

The first file is created with properties that register the addons JavaScript and CSS sources as well as a property which includes the addons spring web context in the storefronts web context.

In the second file it created a dependency from the storefront to the addon. That way during startup spring beans of the addon are created before the storefront beans are created. Also during build, hybris copies the addons web sources into designated folders in the storefront extension.

So as long as you deploy these files along with the other files, you can skip the addoninstall task.

Comment: Thank you, that is the information I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called localextensions.xml inside the hybris config folder where you can select the extensions that your project will use.

Comment: I'm talking about storefront addons here.
https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8adf7365866910149ceb975f778d809d.html